# Solving linear inequalities over rings

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

The concrete problem: for any given $N\ge 1$ I have a system of $2^N-1$ linear inequalities over $\mathbb{Z}_6^N$ which looks like this: for every nonempty $S\subseteq[N]$ there is some $b_S\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ and the inequality $\sum_{i\in S}x_i\ne b_S$. I want to find a solution to all the inequalities at once, of course.

Is there an efficient way to find solution to such a system? To count the number of solutions? To check whether a solution exists? Also, what about more general cases (any number of inequalities, any type of ring, no restriction on the coefficients of the variables in the inequalities)?

Comment: What order are you using in the inequalities?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: In an inequality you use the symbol $\leq$ or a similar one. What does the symbol mean in this case?

Comment: Maybe "inequality" is the wrong word (but I don't know what's the right word). There's no order here, only expressions of the form $x\ne y$ (not equal).

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I misunderstood your question.